# Dynamic route in react link to is not connecting with route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi as I'm new to react trying to do dynamic route, but unfortunately link is not connecting with route,
Thanks in advance, Even I searched for it, I'm unable to sort it out

```
<Route path = "/verify?token/:code"  exact component = {ListEmployeeComponent}></Route>
```

```
<Link to = {`/verify?token/${token.code}`}>here is verify</Link>
```

here is route path and link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are incorrectly defining the routes, you can define in the following ways:

**Method 1:** Using [URL params](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params):

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/verify/token/:code"
    exact
    component={ListEmployeeComponent}
  ></Route>
</Switch>
```

Above will work with a Link as:

```
<Link to={`/verify/token/${token.code}`}>here is verify</Link>`
```

**Method 2:** or, a simple route (which you can use with search params)

```
<Switch>
  <Route
    path="/verify"
    exact
    component={ListEmployeeComponent}
  ></Route>
</Switch>
```

for the above one, you can create a link as :

```
<Link to={`/verify?token=${token.code}`}>here is verify</Link>
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-basic-forked-8n08f?file=/example.js:405-469).